# Manage OPTIONS request to the KeyRock API

Tags: fiware, keystone, identity-management

I´m trying to access the Keyrock API like in the URL : https://keyrock.docs.apiary.io/#reference/keyrock-api/authentication/create-token-with-password-method.

For example, to create a token with user and password, **POST https://keyrock/v1/auth/tokens** like in this web https://keyrock.docs.apiary.io

With Postman I can do a POST but the OPTIONS request doesn`t work, returning in te Reponse "POST,GET,HEAD,DELETE".

The problem is that when I try to do a POST request in a web app to the API, the browser automatically do an OPTIONS request first, and the KeyRock can manage the OPTIONS requests because only allows POST, GET, HEAD and DELETE method.

How can I configure the fiware-idm GE to solve this?
(I think that the problem can be for the CORS configuration)

Comment: Can you describe better what are you facing (problem)? You can edit the question giving more details...